# PX4 software download error

Tags: eclipse, git, toolchain, libopencm3, px4

I have windows 7 32-bit OS. I have downloaded Eclipse, Java, minGW, GIT Bash but am unable to download the firmware. In the steps for toolchain installation, it says to go to px4 toolchain->px4 software download and 3 directories firmware, bootloader and libopencm3 will be automatically downloaded into C:/px4. This is not helping, I'm a beginner. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are referring to "[Toolchain Installation (Windows)](http://pixhawk.org/dev/toolchain_installation_win)".

The step is about [**download the P4x installer**](http://pixhawk.org/firmware/downloads): http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/lomeier/downloads/px4_driver_installer_v10_win.exe

And execute it (as the [YouTube video shows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4L91tU4eHE)): *that will create the folder `C:/px4`.